# Need help on comparing multiple values VBA

Tags: vba, integer, multiplication, subtraction

So i'm making a stat calculator for one of my favorite games I play (realm of the mad god) and I have 24 swords for item 1 and item 2.

http://i.gyazo.com/2ef539f7f18305ae1318013a1dc659d8.png

I want the program to check each sword
the range, damage and amount of shots (missles it fires at a time)
and multiply the damage by the number of shots.

I noticed with the current code I have the displayed value doesn't have decimals
like the damage and range of the weapons have.
http://gyazo.com/06a8471e9db64c7bc5cd9b30a3d952f8

Don't mind the timer button that's for temporary testing to make sure the integers were being changed.

```
    Dim i1 As Integer = 0
Dim i2 As Integer = 0
Dim i3 As Integer = 0
Dim i4 As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If (i1) < (i2) Then
        Label23.Text = "Damage : " & i1
    Else
        Label23.Text = "Damage : " & i2

        If (i3) < (i2) Then
            Label22.Text = "Range : " & i3
        Else
            Label22.Text = "Range : " & i4
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above works but not in the way I was hoping..

But basically what i'm asking is for pointers and code examples on how to effectively and efficiently achieve comparing values (damage, range, shots) of the weapons
and get the program to pick the one that is best.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are dropping decimals is because you have declared the variables as integers, which are not capable of storing decimals.

For more information about data types, give this a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx

But if you will take about a decades worth of experience... for numerics, just stick to longs when you don't need decimals, and doubles when you do. Longs are the fastest type in VBA and Singles bring all the hassle of a double, but with half the space.

There will be occasions when you use other types. For instance most MSFORMS controls in Excel will have their numeric types as Singles and to avoid type conversion weirdness, it's better to just match types. But unless you have a reason... Longs and Doubles will get you where you want to go 99% of the time. (IMO)